# Error 403 - does not have storage.objects.create access to

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to my Firebase Storage using Laravel (PHP).

```
public function uploadObject($bucketName, $objectName, $source) {
    $projectId = 'cloudestate-d10da';
    $storage = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
        'keyFilePath' => __DIR__.'/StorageAcc.json'
    ]);
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket("images");
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "storageacc@cloudestate-d10da.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to images/testezc.png."
    }
],
"code": 403,
"message": "storageacc@cloudestate-d10da.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to images/testezc.png."
}
```

}

I also gave my Service Account "Owner" role but didn't seem to fix the error.

[image: My Google Cloud Console]

Comment: Is the Storage API enabled? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/storage-component.googleapis.com

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.

Comment: we are also facing same issue. Only default bucket works. custom bucket isn't working.

Comment: Did you find a solution. I have the same problem. I enabled the google cloud storage pricing. I enabled the apis: `Cloud Storage for Firebase API` and `Storage API`. I always get the `does not have storage.objects.create access to test-lab...`  My role has nearly all admin permissions. I'm really confused about the error message.

Comment: Do you have a blaze or a spark plan?

Answer (score -1):

First, you must verify that the configuration variables that are used are the same as the project you are trying to run. Try printing the environment variables.

```
console.log(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
```

Firebase establishes by default this configuration. If you want to change this variables you can use.

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

Then proceed to authenticate yourself:

```
firebase login
```

Then list the project that are available:

```
firebase projects:list
```

To view all the project aliases:

```
firebase use
```

Then to match the project configuration variables set the alias you are using to the current local environment.

```
firebase use <alias>
```

Finally, verify the configuration variables are those you needed.